# EJB 3.1 : Singleton bean not getting injected inside another stateless bean though both beans are getting registered

Tags: singleton, ejb-3.1

Here is my bean that is trying to inject a singleton bean **InformationService** :

```
@Path("/information/{name}")
@Stateless (name="InformationResource")
public class InformationResource {

    @EJB
    private InformationService appService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Information getInfo(@PathParam("name") String name){
        return appService.getMap().get(name);
    }

    @PUT
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Information putInfo(@PathParam("name") String name, Information info){
        return appService.getMap().put(name,info);
    }

    @DELETE
    public void deleteInfo(@PathParam("name") String name){
        appService.getMap().remove(name);
    }
}
```

This is the **InformationService** class

```
@Singleton
public class InformationService {

    private Map<String,Information> map;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        map = new HashMap<String,Information>();

        map.put("daud", new Information("B.Tech","Lucknow"));
        map.put("anuragh", new Information("M.Sc","Delhi"));
    }

    public Map<String,Information> getMap(){
        return map;
    }

}
```

Its part of a very simple JAX-RS implementation and I am deploying as war in JBoss 6.1 Final. The problem is that **InformationService** throwing a NullPointerException when I make the proper get request. If I initialize **appService** explicitly, everything works fine. Why is **@EJB** annotation not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jersey as REST implementation? If so, EJB injection is not supported out of the box.

[This link](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/ejb_injection) provides more information on this and also a solution.

Comment: I am using JBoss' implementation of JAX-RS (not RestEasy)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your @Singleton is javax.ejb.Singleton.
Any other exceptions before NPE ?